# Passing variable to event listener with multible call

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling

In a button event function, I have a multible links to download multible files. to dowload these files I have this code:

```
        for (int l = 0; l < itemLinks.Count(); l++)
        {
            string[] sourceParts = itemLinks[l].Split('/');
            string fileName = sourceParts[sourceParts.Count() - 1];
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(itemLinks[l]));
        }
```

Here at the following function for OpenReadCompletedEventArgs I need to know which file's download is completed:

```
    async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string pff = e.ToString();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile =    
                   IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile
                             .OpenFile(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        //Also I need to do some stuff here with FILE_NAME
      }
```

How can I send FILE_NAME value to client_OpenReadCompleted?

I can not keep the value in a global variable since it will change in every call at the for statement, also I have tried to send the variable as += (sender, eventArgs) =>
But I have await in my code which force me to change button function as async

Comment: I have a string like "myaddress.com/file_name1;myaddress.com/file_name2;myaddress.com/file_name3;", I parse it to "itemLinks" array and in a for I call to download those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenReadAsync` has an overload expecting a "userToken" parameter. It has been designed for this very purpose.

When calling `OpenReadAsync`, use this overload with your variable:

```
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(itemLinks[l]), fileName);
```

then, in the event handler, retrieve it:

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = (string)e.UserState;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `await`, a much cleaner solution is available if you use [`HttpClient`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) instead of `WebClient`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(itemLinks.Select(DownloadAsync));

private static async Task DownloadAsync(string itemLink)
{
    string[] sourceParts = itemLinks[l].Split('/');
    string fileName = sourceParts[sourceParts.Count() - 1];
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var source = await client.GetStreamAsync(itemLink))
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await source.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    ... // Use fileName
}
```

I'm not entirely sure whether `CopyToAsync` is available on WP8 (it might be part of `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`). If it's not, you can remove the `GetStreamAsync` line and replace the `CopyToAsync` line with this:

```
var buffer = await client.GetBytes(itemLink);
await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```